# R - Web Form Submission with RVEST

Tags: r, webforms, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a website that has a form that you fill out the dates, and submit. Then download's a CSV.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(rvest)


url <- "http://itc.aeso.ca/itc/public/queryHistoricalIntertieReport.do"

pgsession<-html_session(url)


pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form<- 
  set_values(
    pgform, 
    availableEffectiveDate="943279200000 1999-11-22 07:00:00 MST (1999-11-22 14:00:00 GMT)", 
    availableExpiryDate="1561960800000 2019-07-01 00:00:00 MDT (2019-07-01 06:00:00 GMT)",
    fileFormat="CSV",
    startDate="2018-05-01", 
    endDate="2018-05-02"
  )


html_nodes(pgsession, "table") %>%
html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

It does not appear to be submitted the form components. As all that comes back is a jumbled mess with a "Start Date / Stop Date is required" message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. I don't know exactly what's going on, but my thought process was:

1) There appears to be a jsessionid I needed to get. 
2) It needs to be submitted as a POST request, not a GET request.

```
library(curl)
library(xml2)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

url <- "http://itc.aeso.ca/itc/public/"

# warm up the curl handle
start <- GET(url)

# get the cookies
ck <- handle_cookies(handle_find(url)$handle)

# make the POST request
res <-     POST(paste(url,"/queryHistoricalIntertieReport.do",";jsessionid=",sep="") %s+% ck[1,]$value,
        user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"),
        accept("*/*"),
        encode="form",
        multipart=FALSE, # this gens a warning but seems to be necessary
        add_headers(Referer=url),
        body=list(`startDate`=seq_dates[D],
                  `endDate`=seq_dates[D],
                  `fileFormat`="CSV",
                  `availableEffectiveDate`="943279200000 1999-11-22 07:00:00 MST (1999-11-22 14:00:00 GMT)",
                  `availableExpiryDate`="943279200000 1999-11-22 07:00:00 MST (1999-11-22 14:00:00 GMT)"))


tmp <- textConnection(rawToChar(res$content))

datIn <- read.csv(tmp, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=F)
```

The Body/List section are the fields in the form I that gets filled out, including 2 hidden fields. Found this via F12 dev-tools in Chrome and clicking down until I found the form id's.

The rest I took from here: 
[R web scraper with jsessionid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467515/r-web-scraper-with-jsessionid)

No idea what the User_Agent stuff is, but I'm on a PC, and the Mac stuff still worked.